# rs3 account gone with old school?

Tags: runescape, oldschool-runescape

So, i made an old school mobile runescape account recently with the new mobile app. But when i went to log into my old rs3 account it has reset everything to nothing. And it looks like it almost combined the 2 accounts, it has my old school friends on the friends list and now shares a username. Is there any way to get my account back?

Comment: It sounds like you created a whole new account. You should still be able to log in with your old account details on both games

Comment: I wonder if its worth updating the duplicate question - somethings as you noticed are shared between your accounts (friends list being one of them) but for the most part, your OSRS account is completely separate from your RS3 account.  They share the same login information however.  So when you logged into OSRS with your information, you started fresh, since you never played OSRS before.  What you *have* played before was *Runescape* (commonly called RS3 now).  If you were to use that same login information to play RS3, your character will be where it left off when you last played.

Comment: I don't agree with this duplication. The duplicated question is about logging into OSRS with an existing RS3 account, not about logging into RS3 with a new OSRS account.

Answer (score 3):

Old School Runescape accounts are entirely separate from the RS3 accounts. Every player had to start fresh in OSRS when it was created. You can still use the same log-in information as the RS3 character, but nothing in-game is connected between the two game versions.

Your character's stats and items are still there on the RS3 version, but nothing is carried over to OSRS.